# I need help! NO internet or network connection!

Tags: networking, internet

I am new to Linux and after becoming sick of windows 10 and doing some research decided to try and use elementary OS.  I installed elementary OS on my desktop but  for the life of me after nearly 24 hrs of messing with this cannot get internet or a connection to my network. It is a wired connection. It is getting very frustrating and is not giving a good first impression of Linux for sure.

I don't know if you need to know my hardware or not but I have a 
Gigabyte 990FXA-UD7 motherboard using on-board Realtek PCIe GBE family network controller.

I am about to my wits end with this.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (and thus Elementary OS) seems include an old version of the Realtek networking driver. Updating the driver may fix the problem.

1. On another computer, download the Linux drivers from [this page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2). ("LINUX driver for kernel 3.x..." is the one you want.)
2. Copy the drivers to a USB drive, and transfer it to your Elementary OS computer.
3. Extract and install the driver.

For more information, see [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/583095/486628).